# Writing continuously to file vs saving data in an array and writing to file all at once

Tags: c#, performance

I am working in c# and in my program i am currently opening a file stream at launch and writing data to it in csv format about every second. I am wondering, would it be more efficient to store this data in an arraylist and write it all at once at the end, or continue to keep an open filestream and just write the data every second?

Comment: Write a benchmark and test it yourself using your own data. Which way performs better for you?

Comment: The stream is probably the way to go, but a `StringBuilder` may be better than an `ArrayList` if all the data is stringified and kept in memory.  More perf tests :)

Answer (score 1):

If the amount of data is "reasonably manageable" in memory, then write the data a the end.

If this is continuous, I wonder id an option could be to use something like NLog to write your csv (create a specific log format) as that manages writes pretty efficiently. You would also need to set it to raise exceptions if there was an error.

Answer (score 0):

From what I learned in Operating Systems writing to a file is a lot more expensive than writing to memory. However, your stream is most likely going to be cached. Which means that under the hood, all that file writing you are doing is happening in memory. The operating system handles all the actual writing to file asynchronously when it's the right time. Depending on your applications there is no need to worry about such micro-optimizations.

You can read more about why most languages take this approach under the hood here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/224415/whats-the-philosophy-behind-delaying-writing-data-to-disk

Answer (score 0):

This kind of depends on your specific case.  If you're writing data about once per second it seems likely that you're not going to see much of an impact from writing directly.

In general writing to a `FileStream` in small pieces is quite performant because the .NET Framework and the OS handle buffering for you.  You won't see the file itself being updated until the buffer fills up or you explicitly flush the stream.

Buffering in memory isn't a terrible idea for smallish data and shortish periods.  Of course if your program throws an exception or someone kills it before it writes to the disk then you lose all that information, which is probably not your favourite thing.

If you're worried about performance then use a logging thread.  Post objects to it through a `ConcurrentQueue<>` or similar and have it do all the writes on a separate thread.  Obviously threaded logging is more complex.  It's not something I'd advise unless you really, *really* need the extra performance.

For quick-and-dirty logging I generally just use `File.AppendAllText()` or `File.AppendAllLines()` to push the data out.  It takes a bit longer, but it's pretty reliable.  And I can read the output while the program is still running, which is often useful.

Answer (score -1):

You should consider using a [BufferedStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.bufferedstream(v=vs.110).aspx) instead. Write to the stream and allow the framework to flush to file as necessary. Just make sure to flush the stream before closing it.

Comment: `FileStream` is already buffed and configurable, adding a `BufferedStream` over the top of that is redundant and just allocating more memory